# Why are trains in the Divergent film series running on two tracks?

Tags: divergent, insurgent

In the second *Divergent* movie, *Insurgent*, the train is running on 2 tracks (the engine is using the two middle rails, and the wagons are running on the two side rail pairs). See the 9 seconds [here from 0:37](https://youtu.be/suZcGoRLXkU?t=37) and the top view:

[image: top view of the train showing the engine running in the centre of the two tracks pulling two trains of wagons on either set]

How can this configuration be better than a regular train with twice the length? As I see, it would lose the benefits of having two tracks (they cannot pass a train coming from the opposite direction), the distance between the two tracks need to be constant for the engine (so probably all tracks had to be rebuilt as well), and the wagons can only be loaded from one side each. Limited station length is probably also not an issue (the cost of increasing the station length (or splitting the trains into two when arriving to the station) is probably comparable to rebuilding the stations to have equal distance between the middle rails and special switches for the different tracks).

Comment: Out-of-universe, this is dumb, can't work and makes no sense.  (Note that the sleepers do not connect the pairs of tracks, so the weight of the locomotive will push them apart, dropping the locomotive onto the railbed.)

Comment: This is a "duplex track" configuration. Having them set out like this allows them to have two short but heavy trains pulled by a single locomotive. Troops (or whatever) can then disembark on either side of the train at the platform without needing to carry materiel over bridges and tracks.